# What is this white line in the middle of editor in Spyder?

Tags: python, user-interface, spyder

Pretty much as in the title - the line located vertically in the editor. What is its purpose and how to remove it, since it is pretty distracting.
Thanks in advance.
[image: The semi transparent ine in question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line is nothing more than a visual aid to show you the maximum recommended line length. You can change its position or disable it completely from the preferences menu:

`Tools` -> `Preferences` -> `Completion and linting` -> `Code style and formatting` -> `Line length`.